# Can some please explain this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, image-rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone Explain this jQuery code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904136/can-someone-explain-this-jquery-code)

I have posted this before, but I would like to refine my question (and I can't seem to do it in the old thread).

The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
            var rot=$('#image3').rotate({maxAngle:25,minAngle:-55,
            bind:
                    [
                            {"mouseover":function(){rot[0].rotateAnimation(85);}},
                            {"mouseout":function(){rot[0].rotateAnimation(-35);}}
                    ]
            });
    });
```

It's taken from here: http://wilq32.googlepages.com/wilq32.rollimage222, and there's a demo of the functionality there as well (animating an image rotation - the 3rd demo on the page).

**What I need explained:**

1. I understand that there's a variable being declared -"*rot*", but I can't seem to understand where the declaration ends....
2. When the variable is used, it is used as *rot[0]*, what does *[0]* stands for? is this an array?
3. I've never seen *bind* used like that, the original syntax is

   $("selector").bind( type, [data], fn );

What's going on, then? What are all the commas and *[ ]* about?

4. What I'd like to do, eventually, is use this script to rotate image "X", while "Y" element is being clicked. How can this be done (preferably without "bind")?

Thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend you go through the jQuery tutorials and maybe a few basic JavaScript tutorials. These are very basic questions and seem to indicate you may not have a lot of programming background.

Comment: For reference, the original question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904136/can-someone-explain-this-jquery-code

Comment: @Peter - I strongly recommend you answer his question, if you think it's so elementary, or else leave it alone.

Comment: Thanks @roatin, I was just gonna post it:)

@peter, some pointers would be welcome, I couldn't find any solutions in the jQuery docs, I might be missing something.

Comment: BTW, both *alert(rot)* & *alert(rot[0])* return:
* [object Object] *

Comment: Adam, instead of using alert() for debugging, use the console in Firebug (if you use Firefox) or Web Inspector/Developer Tools (if you use Safari or Chrome) and console.log(rot)--it will give you detailed information about the object you give it, unlike alert() which will only give you a useless string representation.

Comment: Better late than never @AdamTal, I merged your old unregistered account into this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the basic syntactic issues have been explained by others here quite well...

In terms of:

> What I'd like to do, eventually, is
>   use this script to rotate image "X",
>   while "Y" element is being clicked.
>   How can this be done (preferably
>   without "bind")?

Try this:

```
var x=$("#imagex"); //<-- image to be rotated
var y=$("#elemy"); //<-- element to be clicked
var angleOfRotation=45; //<-- angle of rotation

y.bind("click",function(){
  x[0].rotateAnimation(angleOfRotation);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Declaration ends on 2nd to last semicolon. The reference is captured and will be used much later, during the execution of the callback functions passed.

`rot` is a jQuery object, which is not an array but can be indexed like one.

`rot[0]` is the first DOM object which matches the selector `#image3`, i.e. the object with ID image3.

`bind`, in this case, is not the function bind, but part of the options passed to rotate.

Square brackets `[foo, bar]` indicate a literal array of foo and bar. Curly braces { foo: "foo", bar: "bar"} are a literal object with properties foo and bar.

Answer (score 1):

1. The declaration ends at the first semicolon. `rot` is assigned the value that `rotate()` returns (which, in this case, is the same as the result of `$('#image3')`, due to jQuery's [method chaining syntax](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain)). Everything between `rotate(` and the next `)` is just arguments passed to `rotate()`.
2. Yes, `[0]` is array access. `rot[0]` refers to the first ("0th") item in the array `rot`.
3. Here, `{ maxAngle:25, minAngle:-55, bind: ... }` is an "Object literal," i.e. syntax for an Object that has the properties `maxAngle`, `minAngle`, and `bind`. If you assigned this object to a variable `myObject` (instead of just passing it as an argument to rotate()), you could then access its properties like `myObject.maxAngle`, `myObject.minAngle`, and `myObject.bind`. In this case `bind` isn't a function, it's just the name of a property on the object.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! 

So now the only thing I don't get is how to seperate the selector from the functionality, i.e. hover element X to rotate element Y...

Comment: It looks like NWCoder answered that on your previous question.

Comment: Not exactly, it's not animating... he used the basic .rotate(), which is kind of a given...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the missing piece - this is how you use the above code to trigger rotation by another element:

```
var itemYouWannaRotate = $("#imageToRotate").rotate(0);
$("#TriggerElement").click(function(){
    itemYouWannaRotate[0].rotateAnimation(90);
});
```

Thanks guys, all your answers were a big help.

Comment: That's what I said in my answer

Comment: Hey pǝlɐɥʞ,
Sorry, I missed your answer. Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for as you can see.

Adam